# Liberty Maven repo for 17.0.0.1 not found

Tags: eclipse, maven, websphere-liberty

Using the URL:
http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/websphere/wasdev/maven/repository/
as a repository in the settings.xml and then adding the dependencies in pom.xml as described here:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/was_beta/com.ibm.websphere.wdt.doc/topics/localrepo.htm
my libraries based on Liberty v17.0.0.1 are not found.

For example latest version of the basics.jar is 1.2.16 in my server installation, but the website only goes to 1.2.12.

Where should I find the jar files matching what gets installed with 17.0.0.1 for my repository entry in the settings.xml and dependencies in the pom.xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Liberty dependencies were moved into maven central to simplify the process. There is no longer a need to depend on the special repository.

Comment: Thank you -- here is a search URL for Liberty there:
https://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cliberty